# Why loadable creates different chunk modules for the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-loadable, loadable-component, frontity

I'm new in loadable components. Wonder why loadable creates different chunk modules for the same component? Is it normal? Because I feel like it affects performance of the site.

```
import loadable from "@loadable/component";

const LoadableHeader = loadable(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "Header" */ `./Header`)
);

const LoadableFooter = loadable(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "Footer" */ `./Footer`)
);
const LoadableFooter = loadable(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "CityPage" */ `./CityPage`)
);

etc
```

and this how it looks in console network:[image]

For ex, `CityPage` component 8 times  ... is it possible to make just one for each?